# Focus changes to listview once i clear the Edittext

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm using broadcast receiver to show a dialog.So the flow of code is something like:

**Step1** Getting the requestCode value

**Step2** Based on this requestCode the broadCast receiver goes to if or else if or else part

**Step3** If the value that i entered using some scanner into the EditText(i.e Scan) doesn't matches it shows a Toast "Item Not Available".

**Step 4** Once "Item Not Available" toast comes the focus changes to the Listview which is my problem.

**Step5** Again if i pass value to the Scan EditText the Listview get click automatically.

So my question is "How to remove focus from the Listview" and set it to the EditText(i.e Scan).

For Reference I'm attaching the snap with code snippet and the layout.xml.Please have a look and drop your suggestions why the focus is going to the listview.

[image]

.java snippet

```
 final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null) {
loc = mspinner.getItemAtPosition(mspinner.getSelectedItemPosition())
                        .toString();

                final String ItemNo;
                final String Desc;
                final String StockUnit;

                final String PickSeq;

                final String qtyCount;
                final String qtyonHand;
                final Button mok;
                final Button mcancel;
                final Button mplus;
                final Button mminus;
                final EditText medtQtyCount;
                final EditText medtItem;
                final EditText medtdesc;
                final EditText medtuom;
                final DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
                final String[] UOM = null;
                int requestCode;

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(InventoryCount.this);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.quantityupdate, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        InventoryCount.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                //requestCode=Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("idx"));
                requestCode=intent.getIntExtra("idx", -1);
                // create alert dialog
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(InventoryCount.this);
                medtuom = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.edt_mseshipuom_mic);
                mok = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mseshipOk_mic);
                mcancel = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mseshipCancel_mic);
                mplus = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mseshipIncr_mic);
                mminus = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mseshipDecr_mic);
                medtQtyCount = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_shipShiped_mic);
                medtdesc = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_mseshipQtyOrd_mic);
                medtItem = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_mseshipItemNo_mic);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
    }
    else if (requestCode == 0) {
                    // ItemNo
                    /*if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Log.i("Scan resul format: ",
                                intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
*/
                        String itNo = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                        dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
                        MIC_Inventory mic_inventory = dbhelper.getMicInventoryDetails(
                                loc, itNo);
                        dbhelper.closeDatabase();

                        if (mic_inventory != null) {

                            loc = mspinner.getItemAtPosition(
                                    mspinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

                            ItemNo = mic_inventory.getItemno();
                            Desc = mic_inventory.getItemdescription();
                            PickSeq = mic_inventory.getPickingseq();
                            StockUnit = mic_inventory.getStockunit();
                            qtyonHand = mic_inventory.getQoh();// This value gives
                                                                // QOHand
                            qtyCount = mic_inventory.getQc();

                            medtItem.setText(ItemNo);
                            medtdesc.setText(Desc);
                            medtQtyCount.setText(qtyCount);
                            medtuom.setText(StockUnit);

                            mplus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    String a = medtQtyCount.getText().toString();
                                    int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                                    b = b + 1;
                                    a = a.valueOf(b);
                                    medtQtyCount.setText(a);
                                }
                            });
                            mminus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    int c = Integer.parseInt(medtQtyCount.getText()
                                            .toString());
                                    c = c - 1;
                                    medtQtyCount.setText(new Integer(c).toString());
                                }
                            });
                            mok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    /*
                                     * UOM[mspinnerUom.getSelectedItemPosition()] =
                                     * medtQtyCount .getText().toString();
                                     */
                                    MIC_UOMInternal mic_uom = new MIC_UOMInternal();
                                    mic_uom.setLocation(loc);
                                    mic_uom.setItemno(ItemNo);
                                    String updatedqtyCount = medtQtyCount.getText()
                                            .toString();

                                    if (!qtyCount.equals(updatedqtyCount)) {
                                        mic_uom.setQc(Double
                                                .parseDouble(updatedqtyCount));
                                        mic_uom.setUom(StockUnit);

                                        MIC_Inventory mic_Inventory = new MIC_Inventory();
                                        mic_Inventory.setItemdescription(Desc);
                                        mic_Inventory.setItemno(ItemNo);
                                        mic_Inventory.setLocation(loc);
                                        mic_Inventory.setPickingseq(PickSeq);
                                        mic_Inventory.setQc(updatedqtyCount);
                                        mic_Inventory.setQoh(qtyonHand);
                                        mic_Inventory.setStockunit(StockUnit);

                                        dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
                                        String result = dbHandler
                                                .insertIntoInternal(mic_uom);
                                        if (result.equals("success")) {
                                            result = dbHandler.updateMIC(mic_Inventory);
                                        }
                                        dbHandler.closeDatabase();
                                    }
                                    Intent i = new Intent(InventoryCount.this,
                                            InventoryCount.class);
                                    i.putExtra("et", 1);
                                    i.putExtra("LOCATION", loc);
                                    // i.putExtra("ID", ID);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    // InventoryCount.this.finish();

                                }
                            });
                            mcancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    alertDialog.cancel();

                                }
                            });

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();

                        } else {
                            /*
                             * Toast.makeText(this, "Item not available",
                             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             */


                            toastText.setText("Item not available");
                            Toast toast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 410);
                            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setView(toastLayout);
                            toast.show();


                            msearchtext.setText("");
                            /*msearchtext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                            msearchtext.requestFocus();*/
                            /*msearchtext.setSelection(0);
                            lstView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
                            */msearchtext.requestFocus();

                        }
    else if (requestCode == 2) {
    }
    else
                {
                    toastText.setText("Problem in Scanning");
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 410);
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setView(toastLayout);
                    toast.show();
                }
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_green"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_InvTitle"
        style="@style/pageTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/invTitle" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/txt_InvView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_InvTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#2E9AFE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_InvView"
         android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLoc"
            style="@style/textRegular"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="@string/location" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sploc"
            style="@style/SpinnerItemAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:editable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invScanType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/invLocation"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_Search_mic"
            style="@style/EditTextAppTheme_Scan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:gravity="center"            
            android:hint="@string/scan" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioScanBasedOn_mic"
            style="@style/RadioButtonAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioInum_mic"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                 android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                android:checked="true"
                  android:drawablePadding="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/itemno" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioNum_mic"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                  android:drawablePadding="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/manfno" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioUpc_mic"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                  android:drawablePadding="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/upc" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_full_mic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/invScanType" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_fullTitle_mic"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/itemno"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/description"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/pick_seq"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/qoh"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/qc"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/uom"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_msefull_mic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_PO_mic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_OrderLstImport_mic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_OrderLstExport_mic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_OrderLstExit_mic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is msearchtext??

Comment: msearchtext is an editText

Comment: you can try with setting setFocusable() false on listview when not requird

Comment: Thanks brother its working...Thanks a lot

Comment: should I post it as answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101877/discussion-between-pranesh-sahu-and-vivek-mishra).

Answer (score 0):

Add a textwatcher to edit text and check when text is not blank and it is not equal to expected text then only switch the focus.

/* Set Text Watcher listener */

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(passwordWatcher);
```

and check for text once user enter text

```
private final TextWatcher passwordWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() != 0 && passwordEditText.getText().equals("Your expected text")) {
            // show your toast and change focus
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: while entering text to the edittext everything works fine without focusing to listview but when i'm passing value to the edittext using some bluetooth scanner, the focus goes to listview

Comment: give it a shot i feel afterTextChanged event will be trigger in both cases

Answer (score 0):

You should make your listview not focusable by using `setFocusable(false)` when not required and when you get response correctly from barcode scanner then you can again make your listview focusable.